# how to restrict user to select only one checkbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

The following html code is allowing the user to select more than one check box. Could it be restricted to allow the user to select only one check box using jquery. Each check box is in a div element.

```
<div class="wrapper left">
    <div class="col214 left label">
       Current Treatment<em>*</em>  
    </div>
    <div class="col234 left">
        <div>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPD" runat="server" TabIndex="3" CssClass="chkTrt" Text="PD"></asp:CheckBox>        
        </div>
        <div>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHD" runat="server" TabIndex="4" CssClass="chkTrt" Text="HD"></asp:CheckBox>        
        </div>
        <div>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkConservative" runat="server" TabIndex="5" CssClass="chkTrt" Text="Conservative"></asp:CheckBox>        
        </div>
        <div>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkTransplant" runat="server" TabIndex="6" CssClass="chkTrt" Text="Transplant"></asp:CheckBox>        
        </div>
        <div class="divChkOther">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkOther" runat="server" TabIndex="7" CssClass="chkTrt" Text="Other"></asp:CheckBox>        
        </div>
        <div id="divOther" style="display: none;">
            <div class="wrapper left">
                <div class="col216 left">
                    Please specify:
                </div>
                <div class="col256 left">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbOther" MaxLength="200" CssClass="tb" TabIndex="8"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCurrentTreatment" CssClass="lbl" Style="display: none;"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCurrentTreatmentOtherDesc" CssClass="lbl" Style="display: none;"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not make it a radio when user can only select 1?

Comment: As @MilanChheda suggested, use radio buttons.  Otherwise you need to add custom JavaScript to accomplish the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: You can deselect all other check box on click of any one check box.

```js
$(function(){
       $('div.col234.left .chkTrt').on('click',function(){
          $('div.col234.left .chkTrt').not(this).prop('checked',false);
       });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col234 left">
        <div>
        <input type="checkbox" ID="chkPD" TabIndex="3" class="chkTrt" value="PD">       
        </div>
        <div>
        <input type="checkbox" ID="chkHD" TabIndex="4" class="chkTrt" value="HD">      
        </div>
        <div>
        <input type="checkbox" ID="chkConservative"  TabIndex="5" class="chkTrt" value="Conservative">        
        </div>
        <div>
        <input type="checkbox" ID="chkTransplant" TabIndex="6" class="chkTrt" value="Transplant">        
        </div>
        <div class="divChkOther">
        <input type="checkbox" ID="chkOther" TabIndex="7" class="chkTrt" value="Other">       
        </div>
</div>
```

But the best option is to use radio button instead of checkbox as suggested by Milan Chheda

Comment: Thank you for your post. But this code is still allowing me to select more than one checkbox

Comment: You can try with above running snippet which is working. I think you must be facing some other issue

Answer (score 0):

Just make a radio button instead of a checkbox , but if in your case you realy need to use check box  then you have to use javascript

```
function uncheckall(){
   $('div.col234.left .chkTrt').on('click',function(){
      $('div.col234.left .chkTrt').not(this).prop('checked',false);
   });
});
```